# JS в Windows 8. Как перейти с одной страницы проекта на другую?

Tags: windows-8, javascript

Как перейти с одной html-страницы на другую, например, при нажатии div-а? Пробовал WinJS.Navigation.navigate, но почему-то не работает.

Comment: Что за WINJS может location.go/location/href помогут?

Comment: WinJS - объект из встроенной библиотеки от Microsoft для Windows 8. Насчёт location.href, так и сделал, но с помощью WinJS.Navigation.navigate можно передавать всякие параметры на страницу, на которую переходишь.